# Как получить сообщение без вложений? (c#, MailKit, MimeKit)

Tags: c#, mailkit

Подскажите есть ли метод в MailKit который позволяет получить сообщение без вложения, но что бы информация, true or false - есть вложение или нет, была?

Comment: Раздел [Using IMAP](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit#using-imap) есть пример проверки вложения картинки и скачивание ее.

Comment: @Bulson Спасибо